# openpyxl - copy/paste values and styles from one range to another

Tags: python, openpyxl, copy-paste

I'm using openpyxl to create an automated daily report. Two questions:

1. Is it possible to copy values from one range to another range in one statement, e.g. something like,

`ws['A2':'C2'].values = ws['A1':'C1'].values`

Of course this produces `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'values'`, but something along these lines. If not, what's the most efficient way to loop through it?

2. Same question but applied to cell styles. Is there a way to apply a named style to an entire range of cells at once? If not, best way to loop it?

I know there are some answers related to these questions in the Stack Overflow history, but most are dated and many use deprecated syntax.

Comment: No and no and both are covered in the documentation.

Comment: No offense @CharlieClark, as I assume you are the same Charlie Clark listed as a lead author of openpyxl, but there are numerous Stack Overflow posts showing methods and code examples that are not explicitly covered in the documentation. Thus the reason for my post. Some best practice looping code for assigning values and named styles would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I also rely heavily with openpyxl for my daily reports.

#1. I think this is one of the basic python syntax.

```
ws['A2'].value, ws['C2'].value = ws['A1'].value, ws['C1'].value
```

#2. I use loops to style a series of cells, also possible to include values.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

cell_reference = {
    "A1": "Date",
    "B1": "Description",
    "C1": "Debit",
    "D1": "Credit"
}

for ref, value in cell_reference.items():
    cell = ws[ref]
    cell.value = value
    cell.font = Font('Arial', bold=True)

wb.save('Sample.xlsx')
wb.close()
```

Comment: How about for a large range, like `A1:E10`?

Comment: Its possible. My example just show the column headers. Below it are rows of data. My report can fill in a whole page, or two.